# Programmatically detecting / changing custom keyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

Is there any way to programmatically detect installed keyboards and/or change the keyboard to a custom keyboard from within your app? As in, if I wanted to show a toolbar above the text keyboard with shortcut buttons to commonly-installed custom keyboards, could I a) detect the keyboard is installed, and b) change to a given keyboard on tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you want the list of keyboards setup in the Settings app under General, Keyboards.

1. You can determine the primary keyboard:

   ```
   UITextInputMode *currentMode = [[UITextInputMode activeInputModes] firstObject];
   ```
2. You can determine the possible keyboards

   ```
   NSArray *possibleModes = [UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
   ```
3. You can determine when the keyboard changes. This is done by listening for the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` notification.
4. However, there is no API to change the keyboard.

So you can do everything you need except the most important part.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think of something else!